# How to convert a list of strings into a list of integers

Tags: python, excel

In the below part of code **v**   is a list of characters.

```
import collections
import csv
import sys


with open("prom output.csv","r") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    d=collections.defaultdict(lambda : list())
    header=next(cr)    

    for r in cr:
        d[r[0]].append(r[1])   


with open("sorted output.csv","w") as f:
    cr = csv.writer(f,sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

    for k,v in od.items():  
        cr.writerow(v)
```

My output looks like

[image]

I want to map all the characters of my input into an integer, so that instead of a table with characters i get a table with numbers. I tried to use the built in function **ord()** but it doesnt work, since it only accepts single characters as input and not lists. Can you help?

Comment: so v is just a list of characters? i.e. `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']`

Comment: How about v = [ord(i) for i in v] ?

Comment: it actually works. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of letters that you want converting into numbers try:

```
>>> [ord(l) for l in letters]
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

or

```
>>> list(map(ord, letters))
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

Or if you're dealing with capitalized column headings and want the corresponding index

```
>>> letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> [ord(l.lower()) -96 for l in letters]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply an operation to each item in a list:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = map(lambda c: ord(c), a)

print b
>>> [97, 98, 99]
```